# how to collect a particular attribute from a existing file and merge to another file in linux

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-axis

could anybody tell me how to read xml attribute using xslt for file comparison.

### brief description

there are numbers of `<transportReceiver>` tags are there in old xml, i need to read all and update to new xml .

```
<transportReceiver name="http"                  class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
    <parameter name="port">8080</parameter>        
</transportReceiver>
```

basically i want to read `<transportReceiver>` tag and make a collection and append to new axis2.xml file . for this i am using xslt. I have created a xsl file for this .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="axis2.xml" select="document('axis2.xml')" />



<xsl:template match="/transportReceiver">

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i need some help to collect collection of `<transportReceiver>`

Comment: You can try `identity transform` for copying all the elements as is and then make required changes

Comment: @AniketV i am making bit simpler if i want to copy below tag only as it is and paste it to new xml file.
<transportReceiver name="https" class= "org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
                <parameter name="port">8092</parameter>
</transportReceiver>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an approach on how this can be achieved. Let us assume `First.xml` file contains the `<transportReceiver>` node along with other nodes.

First.xml

```
<root>
    <otherNode>
        <otherNodeValue>XXXX</otherNodeValue>
    </otherNode>
    <someOtherNode>
        <someOtherNodeValue>YYYY</someOtherNodeValue>
    </someOtherNode>
    <transportReceiver name="http"  class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
        <parameter name="port">8080</parameter>
    </transportReceiver>
</root>
```

The `Second.xml` is the one where the `<transportReceiver>` node needs to be merged along with its own existing nodes.

Second.xml

```
<rootNode>
    <axisNode>
        <axisValue>AXIS</axisValue>
    </axisNode>
</rootNode>
```

The XSLT below when applied to `Second.xml`, generates the desired output.

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="fileName" select="document('First.xml')" />
    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="rootNode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- copy required node from First.xml -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$fileName/root/transportReceiver" />
            <!-- retain existing nodes of Second.xml as is -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<rootNode>
    <transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
        <parameter name="port">8080</parameter>
    </transportReceiver>
    <axisNode>
        <axisValue>AXIS</axisValue>
    </axisNode>
</rootNode>
```

Comment: Thanks @Aniket excellent solution . 
but the tag always appear in last line of xml . Is there any solution where i can keep the tag at respected place .

Comment: With reference to the provided solution, the node can either be first or last based on how the `<xsl:apply-templates>` is used. If it is needed at a specific position you would need to copy the remaining nodes accordingly. Since the question did not provide details to the position of tag, the solution provides an approach which can be used for further modifications based on actual requirement.

Comment: in that case what should i need to do . Shall i close this question with "Resolved" and create a new one . Let me know.

Comment: Yes. You can accept this answer and open a new question providing the actual XMLs and the output showing the position of the node. Also share the effort that you have taken to achieve the output to avoid downvoting. Also please specify the business case as to why is it necessary to have the node in that specific position.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting the answer. If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer and it's benefits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)